# Flip div after css3 animation loop reaches to 100% and flip back when it came to 0%, without jquery

Tags: html, css, css-animations

```
div{
    animation: fly 5s linear infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;  
 }

@keyframes fly {
    0% {  left:0px; }
    100% { left:100%; }
  }
```

I have a code to animate the div in a loop that is infinite i just want to flip the div with   `transform:scaleX(-1);`
When animation reaches to 100% of left and flip back to `transform:scaleX(1);` when it again came to 0%.

i am trying to use transform:scaleX(-1) on keyframe but it also animate with the fly animation.
Something like this :
               [Click link to see the sample](http://projects.ashishmishra.com/win8apps/example_div.gif)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add additional keyframes that control the `scaleX`. In addition, the `alternate` animation direction won't really work for you: set up keyframes along the entire timeline, reversing direction in the middle. example: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/r4pNk/

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-animation: fly 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: fly 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: fly 2s infinite linear;
    animation: fly 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fly {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0) scaleX(1);
    }
    0.01% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0) scaleX(1);
    }
    49.99% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(300px) scaleX(1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(300px) scaleX(-1);
    }
    50.01% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(300px) scaleX(-1);
    }
    99.99% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0) scaleX(-1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0) scaleX(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is well, but what to do when i define left 100% in keyframe? @Palpatim

Comment: Change the `translate(XXX)` to `left:XXX` as needed. Putting a `left: 100%` may cause your flipped animation to appear off the edge of the container or viewport, though, depending on your overflow settings. http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/r4pNk/2/